# calculate value in new column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Below are my sample table data. There is one order number and the table is sorted by column ITEM. Column BREAK_M only is a running count each time BREAKOUT is True. You can see that other rows for BREAK_MCT show up as NULL. I want a query like the column `LIKETHIS` where the BREAK_M repeats itself until the next value begins and repeats itself.

```
ORDERNO      BREAKOUT  ITEM_ID   BREAK_M    LIKETHIS

2411       True       9290       1              1

2411       False      9291      NULL           1

2411       False      9292      NULL           1

2411       False      9293      NULL           1    

2411       True       9300      2              2

2411      False      9301      NULL           2

2411       False      9302     NULL           2

2411       False      9303     NULL           2
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query to get the desired result.

```
SELECT ORDERNO, BREAKOUT, ITEM_ID, BREAK_M, 
    (SELECT MAX(BREAK_M)
            FROM SampleTable 
            WHERE ITEM_ID <= ST.ITEM_ID 
    ) AS LIKETHIS
FROM SampleTable AS ST
```

Comment: @Nitiesh can you take a look what  i am doing  wrong i try but not getting real result  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8974b/3

Comment: Change the `COUNT` column to `int` and insert `NULL` vulues instead of `N'NULL'` in that column. Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52458/1

Comment: @Nitiesh i am getting Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int In sql server

Comment: Either drop and recreate the table or first update the value `N'NULL'` to `NULL` in `COUNT` column then try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but something like this should work

```
select *, 
    (Select top 1 BREAK_M 
            from sampleTable 
            where Item_ID <= T.Item_ID 
                and Break_M is not null 
            order by item_ID desc
    ) as LIKETHIS
from sampleTable T
order by item_ID
```

EDIT: after looking at fiddle in comment

Try this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8974b/25. The problems were

(1) your fiddle does not have the same columns as your question above, I had to change Break_M to Count. 
(2) Your nulls in the fiddle are not really nulls, they are a string that says 'NULL' which is not the same thing. Depending on what your real database has you may need (is not null) for real nulls, or '<> 'NULL' if they are not. It may be better to ignore this column and use Breakout = 1 (true) instead, like this

```
select *, 
    (Select top 1 BREAK_M  -- OR COUNT, WHATEVER THE REAL COLUMN NAME IS
            from BREAK4 
            where Item_ID <= T.Item_ID 
                and BREAK_OUT = 1
            order by item_ID desc
    ) as LIKETHIS
from BREAK4 T
ORDER BY ITEM_ID
```

Comment: i apply same but the result i am getting is not. you can check this at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8974b/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create table #t(ORDERNO int,BREAKOUT varchar(10),ITEM_ID int,BREAK_M int, LIKETHIS int)
insert into #t VALUES
(2411,'True',9290,  1     ,null)
,(2411,'False',9291, NULL  ,null)
,(2411,'False',9292, NULL  ,null)
,(2411,'False',9293, NULL  ,null)   
,(2411,'True',9300, 2     ,null)
,(2411,'False',9301, NULL  ,null)
,(2411,'False',9302,NULL   ,null)
,(2411,'False',9303,NULL   ,null)

select ORDERNO ,BREAKOUT ,ITEM_ID ,t.BREAK_M 
, ca.BREAK_M LIKETHIS  from #t t

outer apply(select top 1 t1.BREAK_M 
from #t t1 where t1.ITEM_ID<=t.ITEM_ID and  t1.BREAK_M is not NULL
 order by t1.ITEM_ID desc )ca

drop table #t
```